# Text based site for mobile phones?

Tags: text, web, mobile

I tested my site on a mobile device and it loaded pretty quickly. However i had to scroll right to see all of the text. The text was pretty big as well.

How can i redesign my site so i dont need to do any scrolling and have smaller text? I know i I seen this before but i cant remember what site did it.

i removed my css and the device scrolled right until the end of my largest div. So i need css to solve this? What css do i need to make the text not big and not cause the user to scroll (horz) no matter how small his screen is?

Also do i detect the user agent in .NET and link an alternative css file or do i detect which css to use elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

yes you should design an own css-file for the mobile version of your website. either you check the useragent if it's a handheld or you work with the css media type handheld (which is not supported by older browsers) to load the different css-file.

edit:
with css you can also replace images with text

Comment: well 1) I dont know what about a css i could change to make it a mobile version site 2) i dont know how to detect the useragent (outside of c#) to select the proper css (rewriting the css on the fly inside of .NET seems weird to me)